# Managing infrastructure code via SVN

Tags: svn

We are 4 developers (.Net if it matters) that share the project's code via SVN.
The problem we're facing is how to manage infrastructure code via the SVN
The problem:
We have infrstructure solution that is downloaded automatically from the SVN compiled and build (We have abuild server that responsible for downloading the sln and build it)
all the applications that are using the infrastructure responsible to copy the last build
of the infrastructure's DLL from the build server (when the application is built via script\reference).
Now when we version ("branching") each application we need to version also the infrastructure's code (In order to use the infrastructure code that the application used when it was "branched").
Is there a way to "connect" the branched application with it's corresponding infrastructure's branch They both exsits on the svn's server???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this addresses your problem, but you might look into [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html).

This way, trunk and each branch of the applications could include, via `svn:externals`, the appropriate branch of the infrastructure code.